# Jquery - drawing a horizontal line with an arrow with .animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want to be able to draw with .animate an arrow with a horizontal line (->)
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: why dont you use canvas?

Comment: can you show me how to use it?

Comment: Canvas is HTML5 support

Comment: Internet Explorer 9+, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari support the `<canvas>` element. Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, do not support the `<canvas>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6uhqL/

**Javascript**

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(10,50);
ctx.lineTo(150,50);
ctx.lineTo(140,40);
ctx.moveTo(150,50);
ctx.lineTo(140,60);
ctx.stroke();
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid red;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```